# How do I stop a column from wrapping or breaking to a new line in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in the example, everything is perfect in the XS, SM, MD views.  However, in the LG view, I cannot get everything on the same line no matter how hard I try.

I've been working on this for too long.  Does anyone have any recommendations on how to prevent the last column from wrapping to a new line?  Or, do you have a better strategy?

This is part of an `inline-form`with multiple rows.  The reason I have specified a size on the inputs is because it represents the total string length of data that could come back from the server.

- The label should be to the left in MD and LG views

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-inline">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
        <label for="PositionDesp" class="control-label">Position:</label>
        <input id="PositionDesp" name="PositionDesp" class="form-control" type="text" size="50" value="" readonly>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-1">
        <label for="TotalFte" class="control-label">Total FTE:</label>
        <input id="TotalFte" name="TotalFte" class="form-control" type="text" size="6" value="" readonly>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-pull-2 col-lg-4">
        <label for="BasePay" class="control-label">Base Pay:</label>
        <input id="BasePay" name="BasePay" class="form-control" type="text" size="25" value="" readonly>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's Grid system operates on 12-count columns, meaning that every row has to add up to no more than 12.  Your existing code has a `.col-lg` count of 13.  Addressing this should result in expected results:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-inline">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-15">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-lg-5">
          <label for="PositionDesp" class="control-label">Position:</label>
          <input id="PositionDesp" name="PositionDesp" class="form-control" type="text" size="50" value="" readonly>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-3">
          <label for="TotalFte" class="control-label">Total FTE:</label>
          <input id="TotalFte" name="TotalFte" class="form-control" type="text" size="6" value="" readonly>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-4">
          <label for="BasePay" class="control-label">Base Pay:</label>
          <input id="BasePay" name="BasePay" class="form-control" type="text" size="25" value="" readonly>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My Apologies, `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-15">` was accidental and removed from the original post while you were replying.

Comment: Those have nothing to do with your issues on `.col-lg` though.  Your `.col-lg-*` count was still > 12 which is why they were spanning too many lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/g0338maf/1/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-inline">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PositionDesp" class="control-label">Position:</label>
        <input id="PositionDesp" name="PositionDesp" class="form-control" type="text" size="50" value="" readonly>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="TotalFte" class="control-label">Total FTE:</label>
        <input id="TotalFte" name="TotalFte" class="form-control" type="text" size="6" value="" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="BasePay" class="control-label">Base Pay:</label>
        <input id="BasePay" name="BasePay" class="form-control" type="text" size="15" value="" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I should have also  mentioned that the Label must always stay to the left of the field in MD and LG views